# Form Level Validation for Float Datatype in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript, cjsx

I am new to Ruby. I am getting Error while trying to update value of quantity column.

```
ERROR: Out of range value for column "quantity"
```

Quantity Column datatype is float(24). I Want to validate this field with some max length on form level.
Our front end files are cofee.cjsx. I tried with OnBlur and maxLength functions but not working.
If anyone can suggest something Please.
Thank You !

Comment: Please update with the migration with that field and the model.

Comment: @razvans it sounds more like this issue is actually due to a client-side validation. Of course its impossible to tell anything without any actual debugging effort.

Comment: Well, any client side validation needs to be enforced on the server, so model validations should be present.

Comment: Thank You @razvans .

Comment: @razvans do you have idea that how can we validate one field for length(like you can enter only 20 characters in that field) , on onchange function ?

Comment: What are you using? jquery, react?